# Apache Reverse Proxy to multiple applications, obscuring context roots

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy, tomcat8

***Hokay… so…***

I have a series of applications which are deployed to a single Tomcat application server. Let's call them appOne, appTwo and appFoo.

I am fronting these applications with an Apache reverse-proxy listening for appOne.mysite.com, appTwo.mysite.com and appFoo.mysite.com, and it effectively sends traffic where it needs to go using a pattern similar to the following:

```
<VirtualHost appOne.mysite.com:443>
[ ... ]
    ProxyPass / http://serverOne.mysite.com:8080/appOne/
    ProxyPass Reverse / http://serverOne.mysite.com:8080/appOne/
[ ... ]
</VirtualHost>
```

Because of how Tomcat works, each application is granted its own application context on `serverOne.mysite.com:8080`.

However, I don't want the user's to know they're hitting appOne, vs appFoo, so I want to hide it from the URL pattern reported by the browser.

Thus, a request for `appOne.mysite.com` should appear as `appOne.mysite.com` and not `appOne.mysite.com/appOne/`.

**REJECTIONS**

It's tempting to just rename the war file for an application to `ROOT.war` and deploy it because it automagically gets the root context. But in this case, each application should appear to be its own root context (isn't that part of why we use reverse-proxy configurations?).

It's also tempting to suggest that I turn off autoDeploy with Tomcat and provide custom `context.xml` files for each application… but that doesn't solve the issue of applications fighting over the root context designation and ends up being similar to renaming the war file just to get the context root.

It's also also tempting (*see what I did there?*) to suggest that I install multiple versions of Tomcat listening on unique ports… but this gets into complications with asking my organization to open firewall requests for different ports and I anticipate more and more of these applications popping up and sharing this Tomcat instance. (*YAY for single threaded single points of failure!*)

**WHAT ABOUT…?**

I have also considered that there could be programmatic methods I can recommend to the developers to make this more seamless, but I'm not as strong with Java DEV as I am with supporting it's infrastructure. *I am open to suggestions here.*

**It's Possible…**

It's entirely possible the answer is glaring me in the face and I don't see it because I've been staring at the problem for too long, or coming at it from the wrong angle.